# How to resize every image on the blog to fit Google Page Speed test?

Tags: page-speed

I want to optimize the load time of a site that has more than 1200 pages. The site is built using WordPress and has lots of posts. I have improved the image sizes of the pages. What would be the fastest way to reduce the image sizes of the images in the blog posts? The idea I am getting is to use a resizing software on the /uploads folder.

Comment: Is this a Linux server and do you have SSH access? I ask because `jpegoptim` is pretty amazing and can handle this quickly. And for PNG images `pngcrush` is great too. Happy to follow up with a fuller explanation if you like?

Comment: Also, I just noticed [you asked nearly the same question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/27736/11962) five years ago!

Comment: @TomBrossman: Oh yes. Thanks for the letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

## Command-line tools

If you have a Linux machine and SSH access, try recursively batch processing all images on your site with some command-line utilities. These are very fast and free software. For these examples I assume an Ubuntu 16.04 system, but they also work well (with minor adjustments) on other versions and distributions.

### First make a backup

Start by creating a directory 'backups' at the root of your user's /home:

```
mkdir /home/"$USER"/backups
```

Now back up your images directory. This command will create a compressed file of the directory with today's date in the file name:

```
tar czf /home/"$USER"/backups/site-photos-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').tgz -C /PATH/TO/IMAGES/DIRECTORY/ .
```

(Don't forget the space at the end followed by a ".", and change "PATH/TO/IMAGES/DIRECTORY" to your actual images directory.)

To restore later if things go wrong use this command:

```
tar xvzf /home/"$USER"/backups/BACKUP-FILE-NAME.tgz -C /PATH/TO/IMAGES/DIRECTORY/
```

(Change "BACKUP-FILE-NAME.tgz" to match the actual file name, and change "PATH/TO/IMAGES/DIRECTORY" to your actual images directory.)

### Image dimensions

Resizing image dimensions is easy with the 'mogrify' command included with the `imagemagick` package. Use the command `apt install imagemagick` to install it. To scale all JPEG images in a directory and its subdirectories to a maximum of 1000 by 1000 pixelstry this command:

```
cd /PATH/TO/IMAGES/DIRECTORY/
find -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec mogrify -resize 1000x1000 {} \;
```

If 1000 pixels is too large or small for you just change the '1000x1000' value above to 500x500 or whatever you like. If you have images with the **.jpeg** file extension instead of **.jpg** then edit that part of the command as well.

### Image quality and metadata

You can quickly optimize JPEG image file size with the `jpegoptim` utility. Use the command `apt install jpegoptim` to install it. This command will recursively reduce the image quality to 80% and strip all image metadata.

```
cd /PATH/TO/IMAGES/DIRECTORY/
find -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec jpegoptim --max=80 --totals --strip-all {} \;
```

### Other options

You can automate some of the above if you use the Apache HTTP Server with [Google's Page Speed](https://modpagespeed.com/doc/download) module. This goes way beyond just optimizing images, but you can download and install it with this one-liner (as root):

```
cd /tmp && wget https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/linux/direct/mod-pagespeed-stable_current_amd64.deb && dpkg -i mod-pagespeed-*.deb && apt-get -f install
```

## For WordPress on Shared Hosting

For your WordPress site you can use an optimization plugin, [such as this one for example](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/). I don't have any experience with WordPress but searching their plugins site for "[optimize images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=optimize%20images)" returns many results. This is a good alternative if you are on shared hosting and cannot install software (or don't have SSH access).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to resize all of the images, I think you should change the image sizes in WordPress or add a new one with the [add_image_size() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/).

You then need to regenerate all thumbnails/images. You can do this with this WordPress plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

At last you should use an image optimization plugin. I'd prefer TinyPNG but if you want something for free use EWWW Image Optimisation.